# why parameter row implicity has any

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-data-table-component

Why cant I use row in here please help

```
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';

const columns = [
    {
        name: 'Title',
        selector: row => row.title,
    },
    {
        name: 'Year',
        selector: row => row.year,
    },
];
```

make table create table from react